# iphone/ipad app store allow semi-web native app?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I was just wondering and was hoping if anyone here has experience about it.

If one would make a native iphone app (for example with 5 bottom icons) and each icon would load a webpage, would this be accepted by apple?

Answer (score 0):

No one can surely say about the apple will reject or accept this kind of app, because what the apple want is that your app have some utility which one can't get by opening a web page in safari. If your app has some purpose of opening the five different web pages in five different tabs then they will not reject it.

Answer (score 0):

If your app doesn't interest users and have no utility, then probably it will be rejected.
If you think that only these five buttons app which open url is good enough or have some utility, than go ahead and give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably be rejected under the third item in the [AppStore Submission Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html);

> If your App looks like it was cobbled together in a few days, or you're trying to get your first practice App into the store to impress your friends, please brace yourself for rejection. We have lots of serious developers who don't want their quality Apps to be surrounded by amateur hour.

Or in 2. Functionality

> 2.12 Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected